# Data Security on ASP.Net site

Tags: sql, asp.net, razor

I am learning how ASP.NET Razor works and wondering how I implement data security within my application.

I've followed the tutorial here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but am not at the point where I would like to start limiting records returned and preventing access to certain entries.

For simplicity, I have 2 simple tables

```
:Sites - List of all the sites
SiteID (int/pk), SiteCode (nvarchar(6)), SiteName (nvarchar(100))
```

```
:UserSites - List of Sites user has access to
UserID (int), SiteID (int)
```

Currently when it loads using EF, it loads all records of my "sites", I would like to cross check my UserSites table and only load the sites the user has visible. Going forward, how do i also prevent the user from just putting the SiteID within the web link (Sites/Edit?id=3) and edit/access items they aren't supposed to?

I'm coming from winforms/direct SQL queries so my knownledge/experience around this area is quite new. Appreciate any guidance.

Cheers

Comment: Could you post your code relate load Site table data?

Comment: What you described is called custom authorization, so I would suggest taking a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465227/1707033